# Issues with parsing comma separated values using function sscanf

Tags: c, csv, scanf

I'm running into an issue trying to use sscanf to read values from a string, and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[] = "Super Furnace,400,300.000000";
    
    char name[20];
    size_t q;
    double p;
    
    int result = sscanf(line, "%[^,]s,%lu,%lf", name, &q, &p); 

    printf("result = %d\n", result);
    printf("line = `%s`\n", line);
    printf("data read: %s, %ld, %lf\n", name, q, p);
}
```

When I run the following code the expected output should be

```
result = 1
line = `Super Furnace,400,300.000000`
data read: Super Furnace, 400, 300.000000
```

However the generated output is something along the lines of

```
result = 1
line = `Super Furnace,400,300.000000`
data read: Super Furnace, 94536181571648, 0.000000
```

Comment: The correct [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) conversion format specifier for `size_t` is `%zu`, not `%lu`. Using the wrong specifier causes undefined behavior. You are also using the wrong specifier in the `printf` function call.

Comment: Get rid of the `s` after `%[^,]`. Why did you think that was needed there?

Comment: There seems to be a common misunderstanding that `[^,]` is a modifier of `%s` rather than a format specifier of its own.

Comment: Why do you expect `sscanf` to return `1`? Shoudn't you expect it to return `3` (when your code is working properly)?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out as well @AndreasWenzel. I should have changed the result value for the expected output.

Comment: And the fact that the actual result value is 1 tells you that only the first field was matched and assigned.  This is presumably because of the extraneous `s` in the format string, and it is something that you should be checking in your real code -- that exactly the expected number of fields was scanned.

Answer (score 0):

Since `result` is `1`you know that `sscanf()` read only one of the 3 fields. If you change

```
    size_t q;
    double p;
```

to

```
    size_t q = 2;
    double p = 3.3;
```

the output changes to

```
result = 1
line = `Super Furnace,400,300.000000`
data read: Super Furnace, 2, 3.300000
```

Always initialize all variables. Also is useful also to enclose your strings on output, since we cannot see spaces or `TAB`. Just like you did on the previous line...

something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char line[] = "Super Furnace,400,300.000000";
    char name[20];
    size_t q = 2;
    double p = 3.3;    
    int result = sscanf(line, "%[^,],%lu,%lf", name, &q, &p); 
    printf("result = %d\n", result);
    if ( result != 3 ) return -1;
    printf("line = `%s`\n", line);
    printf("data read: \"%s\", %ld, %lf\n", name, q, p);
    return 0;
}
```

gets

```
result = 3
line = `Super Furnace,400,300.000000`
data read: "Super Furnace", 400, 300.000000
```

As posted in the comments note that `%[^,]` is a valid specifier and the `s` before `%lu` will prevent `sscanf()` to see the rest of the line

Comment: `"Always initialize all variables."` -- I disagree with this recommendation. The problem is not the uninitialized variables, but rather that these variables are being read without first verifying that `scanf` was successful.

Comment: Well, @AndreasWenzel, as we see if the user had these values initialized as I said it would be clearer for him that the values were not touched and he would have one more clue that `sscanf()` failed...

Comment: Yes, for debugging purposes, it can sometimes be useful to give variables an initial value. I just disagree with the recommendation to `"always"` initialize `"all"` variables, as that makes the code harder to understand, especially if they are being initialized to a non-zero value.